# Why any thing that comes after execvp or the exec* family of functions will not be executed?

Tags: c, shell, process, exec, execvp

So I know that anything that comes after `exec*` functions will not get executed (if the exec* call is successful of course).

I want to understand why is this so ?
So I developed this tiny little program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    printf("A program made to understand execvp\n");
    char *cmd[4] = {"ls", "-l","file",NULL};
    execvp(cmd[0],cmd);
    printf("This will not be printed!!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

What I do understand is that executable commands like those found in the bin directory are actually executable programs and so when basically call another program from our program.

And I did read somewhere that

**if successful, the exec system calls do not return to the invoking program as the calling image is lost.**

But what does this really means, and why do they not return to the invoking program ? How do they return then ?

Comment: quote: `The exec family of functions **REPLACES** the current process image with a new process image`. In other words, working exactly as written.

Comment: The first line in [man exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) explains this: *"The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image."*.

Comment: Because the `exec` family of function *replaces* your code with the one it loads.

Comment: return to what? The code that called `exec()` is **GONE**. it's not in memory anymore, so there's nothing to return TO.

Comment: So was it you who asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899582/why-the-exec-family-of-functions-doesnt-execute-the-code-after-exec last October?

Comment: @SteveSummit Nope !! that's not me :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said "basically call another program from our program", but that's not quite right.

If you want to call another program from within your program, you can use `system()`.

But if you use the `exec` family, what they do is replace your program with another program.  Clobber your program with another program.  Overwrite your program with another program.

Once `exec` successfully overwrites your program with that other program, there's no trace of your program left to return to.

This is all because of the concept of a *process*.  When you call `system()`, it creates a new process for that other program to run in, and when the other process exits, it can return to your original program in the original process.

But `exec` does not create a new process -- it reuses the original one.

Comment: So how does my program terminates then, or is it in this case that when exec terminates , it just terminate my program too ?

Comment: @Pro: Imagine you are the computer, and your program is a book you're reading.  Calling `exec` is like throwing your book in the fireplace, but immediately replacing it with a different book which you start reading from the beginning.

Comment: Calling `exec` effectively terminates your program -- although the process that was holding your program is still there.  The new program runs in the old process.  When the new program exits, the process terminates.

Comment: For those familiar with BASIC, `exec` is to `system` like `GOTO` is to `GOSUB`.

Comment: @SteveSummit But the file descriptor table is preserved right?

Comment: @2501: Right, there's a bunch of miscellaneous process state that is preserved across `exec`: open files, ignored signals, uid/gid, 'nice' level, certain capabilities/privileges, etc.